# Browser page rendering issue

Tags: html, css, browser, rendering, browser-cache

I'm facing some strange issue with rendering page. When I'm trying to load the page without cache everything works fine. There is the main logo which is on the left side. When I'm pressing enter immediately and make a new request to the same page, the main logo is on the right side. You can check this issue on [THIS PAGE](http://dgstz.de/)

If I make any changes with inspecting, no matter what, the main logo will return to the left side. Maybe something wrong with the sequence of loaded files.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I think that this is a problem that computer scientist can solve rather than a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

The page looks the same to me when I refresh- as shown here:
[Screenshot of site in Firefox on Linux Mint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCWxQ.png)
It would be useful if you uploaded pictures of what you are seeing, and also indicate:
1) Your OS
2) Browser and version

Are there differences if you use different browsers?
Have you [validated](https://validator.w3.org/) the page to see if any errors are found?

This would help others to help you find the problem.
Thanks.